# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Bio'

Tags: python-import, bioinformatics, python-3.7, biopython

I have a code that imports Bio:

> from Bio import Entrez

but this part is red and fails when I run the code, this is the mistake I'm given when running it:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Bio'

I already installed biopython, and tried changing the interpreters (2.7, 3.5, 3.7, 3.8) and nothing helped.
Also I searched for this problem and saw that the soultion sometimes was to copy the package from site-packages to lib directory. also didn't help.
I would love some help.

Also I should mention that I also have another computer with python 2.7, and the code runs perfectly on it.

Comment: You might want to try `conda install -c bioconda biopython` if you have the conda package manager :)

Comment: From the command line, you can install biopython using the interpreter you intend to use, like this: `/path/to/python -m pip install biopython` This way you are use you installed biopython for the correct interpreter.

Comment: I don'y have the conda package (yet)

Comment: also, when trying out: "/path/to/python -m pip install biopython" it says that the requirements already satisfied

Comment: make sure that `/path/to/python` is the same as what the `which python` command returns

Comment: If you are using Python 3.7 in Linux (eg Ubuntu or similar distributions), install Python3 packages with pip3 (eg. pip3 install biopython) @LiranAvda

Answer (score 0):

Solution: it's not the optimal one, but for me everything was fixed once I installed anaconda and changed the pycharm interpeter I was working with the the anaconda's one